# Linking Menu Panel in Dreameaver for easy updating

Tags: html, dreamweaver

I'm fairly new to Dreamweaver, I've been working on a website that contains a bunch of pages that need to be edited. Mainly, the menu/drop down menu tabs need to be updated with new links and or names/etc. Is there a way to link the menu bar with the rest of the pages so I don't have to manually edit each and every piece of code on every other page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of Dreamweaver specific ways (Templates and Library items), and a better way (server include).

Dreamweaver Templates:
This requires that you have all of your pages based on Dreamweaver templates and you have you menu in a non-editable region. Once you edit the menu in the template and save your template, Dreamweaver will ask if you want to update all the pages in the site. If you do so, then Dreamweaver will go through your site and update all pages based on the template and update the menu code in those pages. This method will require that you upload all of the changed files in order to see the new menu on all of your pages. For more on templates:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/dreamweaver/cs/using/WScbb6b82af5544594822510a94ae8d65-7acda.html

Dreamweaver Library Items:
Library items are similar to templates in that there is a code block that you can update and  when saved the update gets cascaded into every instance in the site. Library items are unique in that they are focused on smaller blocks of code that get added to your page. Again, as with Dreamweaver templates, if you make a change, you'll have to upload all of the changed files in order to see the changes on your site.  For more on Dreamweaver library items:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/dreamweaver/cs/using/WSc78c5058ca073340dcda9110b1f693f21-7e49a.html

Server Include:
This option is "better" in that if you make a change to the include file, once you upload only that file, then all pages that reference the include file will automatically display the updated menu. How to implement this option will depend on the specific server language(s) you have available on your remote site. For example, PHP has at least 4 ways to include an external file (such as your menu): [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php), [include_once](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php), [require](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) and [require_once](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php).

If you search google or the search engine of your choice for the language name you have available plus include, you'll get a number of results of how to implement an include for your page.

With this option, you'll need to update all pages that have the menu to reference the include file and upload the changed files, but going forward, changes to the menu will only require uploading the include file in order to update your site.

One word of caution with includes is that you need to be careful with the paths in your include files, specifically if you have pages with the menu on it that are in multiple folders throughout your site. Search for relative and absolute paths for more info.